# Remove selected file(s) by clicking the remove link from the input file multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

My current code can only remove the files from the HTML client slide, but not the actual file list. Meaning, even the file is remove visually, but when I upload it, the file is still remains uploaded.

What can I do to upload from the file list so that removed file will not upload once I hit the button Upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `HTMLInputElement` with `type="file"` produces a `FileList` object that contains the list of files. The `FileList` object is a read only object that cannot be modified.

So while you can remove the file from your custom `list` array and use the shorted list to build your UL, you cannot modify the `FileList` that is a property of the `HTMLInputElement`.

So, the solution is to create a `new FormData()` object, populate that with your form elements, and then append the list of files to the form element individually.

Something like this should work:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var fileList = [];
var fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', setList);
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', sendModifiesList);

function setList() {
  //Convert the FileList Object to an Array of File Objects
  fileList = Array.from(fileInput.files);
  outputList();
}


function sendModifiesList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fileList.forEach(function(file) {
    formData.append('fileList[]', file);
  });
  console.log("These files will be posted: ", formData.getAll("fileList[]"));
  /*************** EDIT *************************/
  // Get the url from the form's action attribute
  let url = document.forms[0].action;
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Create a POST request
  request.open("POST", url);
  // Set up an onload handler to report status
  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      console.log("Uploaded!");
    } else {
      console.log("Error " + request.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.");
    }
  };
  // Send the form to the server 
  request.send(formData);
  /************ END EDIT ***********************/
};

function outputList() {
  var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
  var nodes = document.createElement('ul');
  fileList.forEach((file, i) => {
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    var filename = document.createTextNode(file.name);
    var removeLink = document.createElement('a');
    removeLink.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
    removeLink.innerHTML = 'Remove';
    removeLink.onclick = function() {
      // Remove item
      fileList.splice(i, 1);
      outputList();
    }
    node.appendChild(filename);
    node.appendChild(removeLink);
    nodes.appendChild(node);
  });
  output.innerHTML = '';
  output.appendChild(nodes);
}
```

```html
<form action="/test.aspx">
  <input type="file" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="fileList"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out! I tried implement your solution, but the bullet lists of files did not show. I'm using Asp.NET MVC, is there something I missed? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Randy Casbun, I managed to get your codes to work. But how do I pass the files values to the Controller? Your script doesn't allow me to POST back.

Comment: @Matt - I've edited the code in the answer. Look for /*** EDIT ***/. It now  _1. retrieves the form's `action` attribute to use as the URL to submit the form to; 2. creates an AJAX request; 3. sets up onload handler to report success; 4 Sends the form with the files attached._ This will fail on stackoverflow, so you will need to replace the URL with your server's endpoint URL for your controller. That should do it.

Comment: Randy Casbun how do I call for you if I have further questions that is related to JS and jQuery?

Comment: You are welcome to find me on LinkedIn and message me there.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again!